# How to linearize this if-then constraint?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, logical-constraints

If $x \ge 1$ then $y = y + x$. And, if $x \le 0$ then $y = y$, where $x$ and $y$ are non-negative integer decision variables. I am using GLPK solver.

How do I linearize this if-then constraint?

Comment: The equality $y = y + x$ implies that $x = 0$.  Do you maybe instead want $z=y+x$, where $z$ is a new variable?

Comment: @RobPratt thanks for the comment. It won't tackle my problem. Actually, I want to update the value of `y` by `x` if `x>0'.

Comment: You would still need to introduce a second variable then, e.g., $y_2$, and adjust your mathematical model accordingly. Therefore, the point of @RobPratt still applies.

Comment: The = in linear and integer programming is **not** an assignment. This is quite often cause of confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to update $y$ and not declare a constraint, then assigning $y = y + x$ already handles both cases $x \ge 1$ and $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I think @RobPratt 's anwser can surely handle your problem.
While if you want to extend x, y to real number, here's an idea in wider range to use:
You can introduce a binary variable $\mu$, and add the following constraints:
$x\le M(1-\mu)\tag{1}$
$x\ge 1-M\mu\tag{2}$
$y'\ge y+x-M\mu\tag{3}$
$y'\le y+x+M\mu\tag{4}$
$y'\le y+M(1-\mu)\tag{5}$
$y'\ge y-M(1-\mu)\tag{6}$
where $y'$ means $y$ after update in order to distinguish y before and after update, and $M$ is a big number.

when $x\le 0$, constraints (1) and (2) forces $\mu$ to be 1, so (5)(6) are active while the others are not, which indicates $y'\le y$, $y'\ge y$, therefore when $x\le 0$, $y'=y$

when $x\ge 1$, constraints (1) and (2) forces $\mu$ to be 0, so (3)(4) are active while the others are not, which indicates $y'\le y+x$, $y'\ge y+x$, therefore when $x\ge 1$, $y'=y+x$

Comment: Your (2) forces $x\ge 1$ when $\mu=0$, which makes $y=y+x$ impossible to satisfy.

Comment: @RobPratt It is not (2) forcing $x\ge 1$ when $\mu = 0$, $\mu$ is a variable whose value is determined by the value of $x$, when $x\ge 1$, constraints (1) and (2) forces $\mu$ to be 0, and therefore constraints (3) and (4) are active, that is $y\ge y+x$ and $y\le y+x$, and when two number are both greater than each other, they are equal. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Your constraints prevent $x \ge 1$. If you disagree, please exhibit a feasible solution $(x,y,\mu)$ with $x \ge 1$.

Comment: let's say $(x,y,\mu)=(1,2,0)$, and here I assume 2 here means before update, and my constraints would be:  $1\le M\tag{1}$
$1\ge 1\tag{2}$
$y\ge 2+1\tag{3}$
$y\le 2+1\tag{4}$
$y\le 2+M\tag{5}$
$y\ge 2-M\tag{6}$   there's no conflict, and the updated y would be 3.

Comment: You are proposing that $y=2$ on the RHS and $y=3$ on the LHS.  In a system of constraints, the variables with the same name must take the same value.

Comment: I see, since the asker didnt specifically use different symbols to represent y before and after update, so I didnt either, I'll change my symbols here.

Comment: Yes, and now that you have changed the $y$ on the LHS to $y'$, what you have is a complicated formulation for $y'=y+x$.

Comment: You're right, I was assuming to apply to a more flexible feasiblity domain and not just non-negative integer. I'll add a description about this.

Answer (score -2):

How about small $m = 1e-6$?
So $ y >= y + \frac{x^2}{x+m}$
So if x>0 y is updated by x else not.